# strototime() relative dates to the time

Tags: php, strtotime

Currently, I have the timezone set to `America/New York`.

I have a timestamp of `1448933400`, thats Monday, November 30, 2015 - 08:30 PM. I would like to get a relative time from this current timestamp as the "First Sun of Next Month".

So I am doing the following code:

```
strtotime("First Sun of Next Month", 1448933400);
```

The problem I am having is, is the returned value of `1449378000`.

This is not at 8:30 PM, but instead at 12:00 AM. Is there an easy way to get relative dates to retain the relative time of the source timestamp?

Comment: Use DateTime and DateInterval objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible answers, but what you can do is first calculate the time offset for the day of your timestamp and apply it to the result:

```
<?php
$stamp = 1448933400;
$offset = $stamp - strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $stamp));
var_dump(strtotime("First Sun of Next Month", $stamp) + $offset);
?>
```

**Output**

```
int(1449451800) // or "2015-12-06 20:30:00"
```